# Anyone interpretation of the ratio between the derivative and the square of the function?

Tags: derivatives, curves, ratio

so I was wondering if anyone has ever heard of any usage, or came across at some point, of interpretation of what does $\frac{f'}{f^2}$ represents for the scalar function? Or equivalently for $\frac{f''}{f'^2}$.
Any ideas are most welcome

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative

Comment: That is negative the slope of the reciprocal....

Comment: I am not aware of a handy interpretation but your second term is not equivalent to your first one - so I am sure the interpretations will also differ from each other

Comment: Note that $(-1/f)'=f'/f^2$

Comment: Just to point why the two terms are equivalent - the second term is the same as the first term, but just applied to $f'$ rather than $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a curve is the graph of $y = f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is differentiable,
then at any point $(x,f(x))$ on the curve, 
the slope of the line tangent to the curve is $f'(x)$ and the
slope of the line perpendicular to the curve at that point is $-1/f'(x)$.
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left(-\frac{1}{f'(x)} \right) = \frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2},
$$
so $f''/(f')^2$ is the rate of change (with respect to $x$)
of the slope of the line perpendicular to the curve.

So in a sense it's a measure of curvature, but not a particularly
satisfactory one (at least, no more satisfactory than regarding $f''$,
which is the rate of change of the slope of the tangent line, 
as a measure of curvature).

It's also in some sense complementary to $f''$, since it relates to the
perpendicular line similarly to the way in which $f''$ relates to the tangent line.

If instead we have a graph of $y = g(x)$ where $f = g'$, then
$f'/f^2$ is the same as $g''/(g')^2$.

Comment: You sir deserve a beer. Although, I'm not sure what are the consequences of this, I'm really glad that you saved me tons of time searching how to interpret this. If you are somewhere in London feel free to collect the beer!

Comment: Just to ask is there any literature on using this measure for curvature where I can continue reading?